# Using WMTS Imagery in QGIS

Tags: qgis, imagery, wmts

A county in my area offers aerial imagery via WMTS.  In the past I've been able to use this with ArcMap, but I no longer have an ArcMap license and would like to use it with QGIS 3.30.  I can establish the connection (apparently), but when I add the imagery title to my map I get an error icon (red exclamation point in a red triangle) and no imagery.  Clicking on the icon I have the option to repair the connection, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

If anyone would care to test the connection, here's the link:

https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/wmts.xml

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to use the `Layer > Add Layer > Add XYZ Layer...` method.

Specifying `.../{z}/{x}/{y}.png` to fit with the  GoogleMapsCompatible tiling.

The full URL to specify would be (exactly this):

```
https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/3inch_Orthos/{z}/{x}/{y}.png
```

QGIS will work out and substitute the values for z, x, and y depending on the zoom level/scale of the map.

For example an individual tile request would end up like:

[image: https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/3inch_Orthos/13/1316/3154.png]

> https://services.sanborn.com/geo_caches/312021386_Solano_County_Oblique/3inch_Orthos/13/1316/3154.png

Where:

- `13` is `{z}`, which is the `{TileMatrix}` value
- `1316` is `{x}`, which is the `{TileCol}` value
- `3154` is `{y}`, which is the `{TileRow}` value

Full coverage in QGIS is:

[image: Full extent of AP for service]

For a fuller understanding of tiling systems including the `GoogleMapsCompatible` system see: [OGC Two Dimensional Tile Matrix Set and Tile Set Metadata](https://docs.ogc.org/is/17-083r4/17-083r4.html)